# Combined results of multiple stored procedures to a single XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sql-insert

SQL Server 2014: looking for a solution as posted in [Combined results from multiple stored procedures to an XML][1]  [1]: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1377879-21-1.aspx

I want the output to be like

```
<root>
  <Products>
    <...>
  </Products>
  <Colours>
    <...>
  </Colours>
  <Sizes>
     <...>
  </Sizes>
</root>
```

And the code:

```
DECLARE @TempExportTable TABLE
(
   Products XML,
   Colours XML,
   Sizes XML
)

INSERT INTO @TempExportTable VALUES
(
    EXEC ('
       EXEC [dbo].[spGetProductsDesc] @tId FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS;
       EXEC [dbo].[spGetColoursDesc] @tId FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS;
       EXEC [dbo].[spGetSizesDesc] @tId FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS;
   ');
)

SELECT 
   Products as '*',
   Colours as '*',
   Sizes as '*' 
from @TempExportTable 
FOR XML PATH('ExportList')
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Is there any reason, why your `spGet....` routines are *stored procedures*? If they were scalar functions or - maybe even better - one TVF returning all XMLs at once, it would be much easier... Btw: It's recommended not to use prefixes like your "sp", especially "sp_" which is reserved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that these SPs deliver structurally not identical row sets probably. SPs are not the right way just to read data... Don't know what you are doing in your SPs, but this might be much easier with TVFs

Following an example how you could achieve what you want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test1 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1,'Test1_1'),(2,'Test1_2')) AS tbl(t1a,t1b);
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test2
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('a','Test1_A',100),('b','Test1_B',200)) AS tbl(t2a,t2b,t2c);
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test3
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('a'),('b')) AS tbl(t3);
END
GO

--Here starts your solution
--First we need tables to fill the SPs results into
--The column's names don't have to be the same as delivered from the SP...
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(t1x INT,t1y VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t1 EXEC dbo.Test1;

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(t1x VARCHAR(100),t2y VARCHAR(100),t3z INT);
INSERT INTO @t2 EXEC dbo.Test2;

DECLARE @t3 TABLE(t3x VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t3 EXEC dbo.Test3;

SELECT (SELECT * FROM @t1 FOR XML PATH('T1_Row'),ROOT('T1'),TYPE)
      ,(SELECT * FROM @t2 FOR XML PATH('T2_Row'),ROOT('T2'),TYPE)
      ,(SELECT * FROM @t3 FOR XML PATH('T3_Row'),ROOT('T3'),TYPE)
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root')
GO

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Test1;
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Test2;
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Test3;
```

Exactly the same result, but much easier to call was this approach with scalar functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test1()
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1,'Test1_1'),(2,'Test1_2')) AS tbl(t1a,t1b) FOR XML PATH('T1_Row'),ROOT('T1'));
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test2()
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('a','Test1_A',100),('b','Test1_B',200)) AS tbl(t2a,t2b,t2c) FOR XML PATH('T2_Row'),ROOT('T2'));
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test3()
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('a'),('b')) AS tbl(t3) FOR XML PATH('T3_Row'),ROOT('T3'));
END
GO


SELECT (SELECT dbo.Test1())
      ,(SELECT dbo.Test2())
      ,(SELECT dbo.Test3())
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root')
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.Test1;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.Test2;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.Test3;
```

The result in both cases:

```
<root>
  <T1>
    <T1_Row>
      <t1x>1</t1x>
      <t1y>Test1_1</t1y>
    </T1_Row>
    <T1_Row>
      <t1x>2</t1x>
      <t1y>Test1_2</t1y>
    </T1_Row>
  </T1>
  <T2>
    <T2_Row>
      <t1x>a</t1x>
      <t2y>Test1_A</t2y>
      <t3z>100</t3z>
    </T2_Row>
    <T2_Row>
      <t1x>b</t1x>
      <t2y>Test1_B</t2y>
      <t3z>200</t3z>
    </T2_Row>
  </T2>
  <T3>
    <T3_Row>
      <t3x>a</t3x>
    </T3_Row>
    <T3_Row>
      <t3x>b</t3x>
    </T3_Row>
  </T3>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who responded. But the EXEC SP with INSERT does not work straight away, it needs OPENQUERY. But this OPENQUERY doesnt seem to take parameter in the form of a variable which I have to supply to the SP. One of the above answers will produce more than one xml, I need all of them in just one xml. I dumped the 3 SPs, and combined them to one SP to get the results. But the alternate answer would be Scalar or multi-valued functions as @Shnugo suggested. Thanks for trying.

Comment: regarding OPENQUERY, you got it wrong. I meant the INSERT-EXEC doesnt work straight away, the proc has to be executed within OPENQUERY. But there was difficult in passing variable to OPENQUERY.  Multi-values functions would have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (SP must output xml or nvarchar like xml data):

```
DECLARE @TempExportTable TABLE (Results xml);

INSERT INTO @TempExportTable
EXEC [dbo].[spGetProductsDesc] @tId;
--The output must be like:
--<Products>
--  <Product id="1" name="pr1" />
--  <Product id="2" name="pr2" />
--  ...
--</Products>

INSERT INTO @TempExportTable
EXEC [dbo].[spGetColoursDesc] @tId;
--The output must be like:
--<Colours>
--  <Colour id="1" name="red" />
--  <Colour id="2" name="white" />
--  ...
--</Colours>

INSERT INTO @TempExportTable
EXEC [dbo].[spGetSizesDesc] @tId;
--
--<Sizes>
--  <Size id="1" name="S" />
--  <Size id="2" name="M" />
--  ...
--</Sizes>

SELECT Results as '*'
FROM @TempExportTable 
for xml PATH('') ,ROOT('root');
```

Results:

```
<root>
  <Products>
    <Product id="1" name="pr1" />
    <Product id="2" name="pr2" />
    <Product id="3" name="pr3" />
  </Products>
  <Colours>
    <Colour id="1" name="red" />
    <Colour id="2" name="white" />
    <Colour id="3" name="green" />
  </Colours>
  <Sizes>
    <Size id="1" name="S" />
    <Size id="2" name="M" />
    <Size id="3" name="L" />
  </Sizes>
</root>
```

Comment: You assume, that all SPs are returning nothing else than **one** textual or XML column. Did you try this? If your table contains several textual contents, you would get several XML nodes with no root. All were named "ExportList". If the content is pre-defined XML, you would end up with a bunch of `&lt;&gt;&lt;&gt;&lt;&gt;&lt;&gt;` ...

Comment: Well, I use same type of query when I need to put 1 column data (such as xml) in 1 table to get 1 big result in the end.

Comment: Yes, but did you try this in combination with `FOR XML PATH()`? Try it as well with "naked" text, with "xml as varchar" and with "real" xml. None of them will look like the OP wanted it...

Comment: OK, this'd be the only chance to get it working with this approach. But the SPs must deliver one ready made XML (**crying for scalar function!!**) and your temp table must use "real" XML too. Finally you have to get rid of the "ExportList" nodes and you must add a root node :-). In this case it might be even simpler to keep the whole lot in string concatenation :-)

Comment: (facepalm) edit! Thanks, I rarely (read as never) use `FOR XML PATH()` for that kind of cases, but now sure will.

Comment: And  here is mine! Scalar functions are nice for this kind of things, as I see from your answer.

Comment: It is something **very common** to use SPs for **reading** data. I do not know why... Especially if you cannot take the resultset "as delivered", if you want to do something with your data, it is pure pain in the neck! Scalar functions (in this case) and even better *table valued functions* (but only if "inline syntax" without `BEGIN` and `END`) or a `VIEW` are **much better** .

Comment: I just really want to know where you found out that the Results as '*' would cause the xml to be used as is instead of nesting each row under a <results> element? That was the gem I found in your response here :)

Comment: @Daniel haven't found old source, but here is one new https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/columns-with-a-name-specified-as-a-wildcard-character